# getUserMedia working on website but not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, getusermedia

I am using getusermedia to record audio in my website. I've included the javascript of getusermedia. The record function works fine on website but doesn't even popup for permission in when opened on mobile.

```js
var constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: false
}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
  permissiongiven = 1;
});
```

this is the sample code which prompt me for permission but doesn't work on mobile. 
How can I make it work on both device. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Edit :- The code is now working fine on mobile as well. Maybe it was solved from chrome updates or security certificates of website. Thanks all for help.

Comment: Which mobile OS/browser are you using?

Comment: I am using android with Marshmallow version and chrome browser.

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Comment: Thanks everyone but the issue is resolved automatically. I guess the chrome app has updated its features to allow the microphone access from websites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that on mobile devices, you have to use SSL to use `getUserMedia()`. Check out if you're accessing your website with a `http://` prefix. Try change it to `https://` and it should work fine.

Comment: Trying to develop on localhost, can't use https there, too shame.

Answer (score 1):

I found this website useful in answering this question

https://caniuse.com/#search=getusermedia

It says getUserMedia only supported from Chrome for Android version 70 (released Oct 16 2018)

Comment: That's not right. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Browser_compatibility) has getUserMedia in Chrome for Android since 52.

Comment: Any progress with this?

Comment: Progress on what? caniuse is wrong and MDN is right AFAIK. [Wfm](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/pz5pynyf/show) on Chrome for Android 68 for instance.

Comment: Has the OP made any progress with his problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Browser_compatibility), then make sure your browser supports it. You need Chrome for Android 52+ it says. FWIW 68 [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/pz5pynyf/show).

You should also feature-check and catch errors:

```js
if (!navigator.mediaDevices) {
  console.log("Sorry, getUserMedia is not supported");
  return;
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(stream => permissiongiven = 1)
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Depending on the error you get, we might learn more.

- `NotFoundError` means no camera or mic detected on the device.
- `NotAllowedError` means user permission not granted, or you're in an iframe or not https.

Answer (score 0):

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia Browser compatibility

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i had no idea that `navigator.getUserMedia` was deprecated (at least for Samsung, which is what i was testing on), and i found [this article on web audio](https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/web-audio-on-different-platforms-67fc9ffc2c4e) with a code sample that i barely modified:

```js
function initGetUserMedia() {
  navigator.mediaDevices = navigator.mediaDevices || {}
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia || function(constraints) {
    let getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
    if (!getUserMedia) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia not supported by this browser'));
    } else {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with ssl site:

```
<script>var constraints = {audio: true, video: false}
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {{permissiongiven = 1;});</script>
```